# Android - How do I call invalidate() method from another class?

Tags: java, android, static

I need to call invalidate() method from my MainActivity class. I can call it from my CanvasView class, but from MainActivity, it gives me an error. Says invalidate is non-static method. How do I get past this? I have searched and tried some solutions, but haven't got it to work.

I want to delete drawn items from the screen, but when I select Undo from menu list, it won't update the screen. Only when I touch the screen, it Undos elements.

My CanvasView class

```
package com.example.HW3;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.Paint;
import android.graphics.Path;
import android.graphics.Point;
import android.graphics.Rect;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;
/**
 * Android Kimp.
 * @author Martin
 *
 */
public class CanvasView extends View {
/**
 * Rectangles.
 */
    private Rect rectangle = new Rect();
/**
 * These help calculating rectangle coordinates.
 */
    private float d1 = 0, d2 = 0;
/**
 * Canvas.
 */
    private Canvas canvas = new Canvas();
/**
 *  Paint to draw shapes.
 */
    private Paint paint = new Paint();
    /**
     *  Paint to draw shapes.
     */
    private Paint paint2 = new Paint();
    /**
     *  Paint to draw shapes.
     */
    private Paint paint3 = new Paint();
    /**
     *  Paint to draw shapes.
     */
    private Paint paint4 = new Paint();
/**
 * Path.
 */
    private Path path = new Path();
/**
 * Point.
 */
    private Point point = new Point();
/**
 * List for lines.
 */
    private static List<Path> lines = new ArrayList<Path>();
    private static List<Path> lines2 = new ArrayList<Path>();
/**
 * List for points.
 */
    private static List<Point> points = new ArrayList<Point>();
    private static List<Point> points2 = new ArrayList<Point>();
/**
 * List for rectangles.
 */
    private static List<Rect> rectangles = new ArrayList<Rect>();
    private static List<Rect> rectangles2 = new ArrayList<Rect>();

    private static List<Integer> elements = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    private static List<Integer> elements2 = new ArrayList<Integer>();
/**
 * Touch coordinates.
 */
    private float x, startX, endX;
/**
 * Touch coordinates.
 */
    private float y, startY, endY;
/**
 * This checks whether user draws a line or a point.
 */

    private int whichShape;

    private boolean touchStarted = false;
/**
 * Enum to hold the value of DrawMode, whether user wants to draw lines or rectangles.
 *
 */
    public enum undoRedo {
        DoUndoRedo, DoNothing
    };

    public static undoRedo currentState = undoRedo.DoNothing;

    public enum DrawMode {
        /**
         * DrawMode possibilities.
         */
        FreeDrawMode, RectDrawMode, SelectAndDrag
    };
/**
 * Sets current DrawMode, when application starts.
 */
    public static DrawMode currentDrawMode = DrawMode.FreeDrawMode;
/**
 * Sets DrawMode.
 * @param newDrawMode
 */
    final Handler handler = new Handler();
    /**
     * Runnable interface to detect long press.
     */
    Runnable mLongPressed = new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            for (int i = 0; i < getRectangles().size(); i++) {
            Log.i("", "Long press!");
            Rect a = getRectangles().get(i);
            System.out.println(a + " " + i);
            double x = getRectangles().get(i).left;
            System.out.println(a + " " + x);
            currentDrawMode = DrawMode.SelectAndDrag;
        }
        }
    };
/**
 * CanvasView.
 * @param context
 * @param attrs
 */



    public CanvasView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);

        paint.setAntiAlias(true);
        paint.setStrokeWidth(3);
        paint.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
        paint.setStrokeJoin(Paint.Join.ROUND);

        paint2.setAntiAlias(true);
        paint2.setStrokeWidth(3);
        paint2.setColor(Color.RED);
        paint2.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
        paint2.setStrokeJoin(Paint.Join.ROUND);


        paint3.setAntiAlias(true);
        paint3.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        paint3.setStrokeWidth(3);
        paint3.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
        paint3.setStrokeJoin(Paint.Join.ROUND);

        paint4.setAntiAlias(true);
        paint4.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        paint4.setStrokeWidth(3);
        paint4.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
        paint4.setShadowLayer(10,5,5,Color.BLACK);
        paint4.setStrokeJoin(Paint.Join.ROUND);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {

        for (Rect r : getRectangles()) {
            canvas.drawRect(r, paint);
        }
        canvas.drawRect(rectangle, paint3);

        for (Path p : getLines()) {
            canvas.drawPath(p, paint);
        }
        canvas.drawPath(path, paint2);

        for (Point point : getPoints()) {
            canvas.drawCircle(point.x, point.y, 1, paint);
    }
    }
    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
        x = event.getX();
        y = event.getY();

        if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
            handler.postDelayed(mLongPressed, 500);
        }
        if ((event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE)
            || (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP)) {
            handler.removeCallbacks(mLongPressed);
        }
        if (currentDrawMode == DrawMode.FreeDrawMode) {
            switch (event.getAction()) {
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                // Set new starting point
                paint2.setColor(Color.RED);
                path = new Path();
                path.moveTo(x, y);
                touchStarted = true;
                break;

            case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                touchStarted = false;
                path.lineTo(x, y);

                break;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                if (touchStarted) {
                    point = new Point();
                    point.x = (int) x;
                    point.y = (int) y;
                    paint2.setColor(Color.BLACK);
                    whichShape = 1;
                    getElements().add(whichShape);
                    getPoints().add(point);
                    getElements2().clear();
                    touchStarted = false;
                    System.out.println("here");
                } else {
                    System.out.println("there");
                    paint2.setColor(Color.BLACK);
                    whichShape = 2;
                    getElements().add(whichShape);
                    getLines().add(path);
                    getElements2().clear();
                }
                break;
            default:
                return false;
            }
        } else if (currentDrawMode == DrawMode.RectDrawMode) {

            switch (event.getAction()) {
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                // Set a new starting point
                rectangle = new Rect();
                paint3.setColor(Color.RED);
                startX = event.getX();
                startY = event.getY();
                System.out.println("down");

                break;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                endX = event.getX();
                endY = event.getY();
                System.out.println("move");
                System.out.println(startX + " " + endX + " " + startY + " " + endY);

                if (startX >= endX && startY >= endY) {

                    rectangle.set((int) endX, (int) endY, (int) startX,
                            (int) startY);
                    canvas.drawRect(rectangle, paint2);
                } else if (startX >= endX && startY <= endY) {
                    d1 = startX + (endX - startX);

                    d2 = startY + (endY - startY);

                    rectangle.set((int) d1, (int) startY, (int) startX,
                            (int) d2);
                    canvas.drawRect(rectangle, paint3);
                } else if (startX <= endX && startY >= endY) {

                    d1 = startY + (endY - startY);
                    d2 = startX + (endX - startX);

                    rectangle.set((int) startX, (int) d1, (int) d2,
                            (int) startY);
                    canvas.drawRect(rectangle, paint3);
                    System.out.println("olen siin");
                } else {

                    rectangle.set((int) startX, (int) startY, (int) endX,
                            (int) endY);
                    canvas.drawRect(rectangle, paint3);
                }
                break;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                System.out.println("up");
                paint3.setColor(Color.BLACK);
                whichShape = 3;
                getElements().add(whichShape);
                getRectangles().add(rectangle);
                getElements2().clear();
                break;
            default:    
                return false;
            }
        } else if (currentDrawMode == DrawMode.SelectAndDrag) {
            switch (event.getAction()) {
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:


                break;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:

                break;
            default:
                return false;
            }
        }
        // Makes our view repaint and call onDraw
        invalidate();
        return true;
    }

    public static List<Integer> getElements() {
        return elements;
    }

    public static void setElements(List<Integer> elements) {
        CanvasView.elements = elements;
    }

    public static List<Point> getPoints() {
        return points;
    }

    public static void setPoints(List<Point> points) {
        CanvasView.points = points;
    }

    public static List<Path> getLines() {
        return lines;
    }

    public static void setLines(List<Path> lines) {
        CanvasView.lines = lines;
    }

    public static List<Rect> getRectangles() {
        return rectangles;
    }

    public static void setRectangles(List<Rect> rectangles) {
        CanvasView.rectangles = rectangles;
    }

    public static List<Point> getPoints2() {
        return points2;
    }

    public static void setPoints2(List<Point> points2) {
        CanvasView.points2 = points2;
    }

    public static List<Integer> getElements2() {
        return elements2;
    }

    public static void setElements2(List<Integer> elements2) {
        CanvasView.elements2 = elements2;
    }

    public static List<Path> getLines2() {
        return lines2;
    }

    public static void setLines2(List<Path> lines2) {
        CanvasView.lines2 = lines2;
    }

    public static List<Rect> getRectangles2() {
        return rectangles2;
    }

    public static void setRectangles2(List<Rect> rectangles2) {
        CanvasView.rectangles2 = rectangles2;
    }
}
```

My MainActivity class

```
package com.example.HW3;

import com.example.HW3.CanvasView.undoRedo;
import com.example.androiddrawing.R;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.Window;
import android.view.WindowManager;
/**
 * Android application.
 * @author Martin
 *
 */
public class MainActivity extends Activity {


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, 
                                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == R.id.default_drawing) {
            CanvasView.currentDrawMode = CanvasView.DrawMode.FreeDrawMode;
            return true;
        } else if (id == R.id.draw_rectangle) {
            CanvasView.currentDrawMode = CanvasView.DrawMode.RectDrawMode;
            return true;
        } else if (id == R.id.undo) {
            int listSize = CanvasView.getElements().size();
              System.out.println(CanvasView.getElements().size());
              if (CanvasView.getElements().size() == 0) {
                return true;  
              } else if (CanvasView.getElements().get(listSize - 1) == 1) {

                  // I WANT TO CALL INVALIDATE() FROM HERE CanvasView.getPoints2().add(CanvasView.getPoints().get(CanvasView.getPoints().size() - 1));
                  CanvasView.getElements2().add(1);
                  CanvasView.getPoints().remove(CanvasView.getPoints().size() - 1);
                  CanvasView.getElements().remove(CanvasView.getElements().size() - 1);
                  CanvasView.currentState = CanvasView.undoRedo.DoUndoRedo;
                  return true;
              } else if (CanvasView.getElements().get(listSize - 1) == 2) {

                  CanvasView.getLines2().add(CanvasView.getLines().get(CanvasView.getLines().size() - 1));
                  CanvasView.getElements2().add(2);
                  CanvasView.getLines().remove(CanvasView.getLines().size() - 1);
                  CanvasView.getElements().remove(CanvasView.getElements().size() - 1);
                  CanvasView.currentState = CanvasView.undoRedo.DoUndoRedo;
                  return true;
              } else if (CanvasView.getElements().get(listSize - 1) == 3) {

                  CanvasView.getRectangles2().add(CanvasView.getRectangles2().get(CanvasView.getRectangles2().size() - 1));
                  CanvasView.getElements2().add(3);
                  CanvasView.getRectangles().remove(CanvasView.getRectangles().size() - 1);
                  CanvasView.getElements().remove(CanvasView.getElements().size() - 1);
                  CanvasView.currentState = CanvasView.undoRedo.DoUndoRedo;
                  return true;
              }
            return true;
        } else if (id == R.id.redo) {
            int listSize2 = CanvasView.getElements2().size();
              System.out.println(CanvasView.getElements2().size());
              if (CanvasView.getElements2().size() == 0) {
                return true;  
              } else if (CanvasView.getElements2().get(listSize2 - 1) == 1) {

                  CanvasView.getPoints().add(CanvasView.getPoints2().get(CanvasView.getPoints2().size() - 1));
                  CanvasView.getPoints2().remove(CanvasView.getPoints2().size() - 1);
                  CanvasView.getElements2().remove(CanvasView.getElements2().size() - 1);
                  CanvasView.getElements().add(1);
                  CanvasView.currentState = CanvasView.undoRedo.DoUndoRedo;
                  return true;
              } else if (CanvasView.getElements2().get(listSize2 - 1) == 2) {

                  CanvasView.getLines().add(CanvasView.getLines2().get(CanvasView.getLines2().size() - 1));
                  CanvasView.getLines2().remove(CanvasView.getLines2().size() - 1);
                  CanvasView.getElements2().remove(CanvasView.getElements().size() - 1);
                  CanvasView.getElements().add(2);
                  CanvasView.currentState = CanvasView.undoRedo.DoUndoRedo;
                  return true;
              } else if (CanvasView.getElements2().get(listSize2 - 1) == 3){

                  CanvasView.getRectangles().add(CanvasView.getRectangles2().get(CanvasView.getRectangles2().size() - 1));
                  CanvasView.getRectangles2().remove(CanvasView.getRectangles2().size() - 1);
                  CanvasView.getElements2().remove(CanvasView.getElements2().size() - 1);
                  CanvasView.getElements().add(3);
                  CanvasView.currentState = CanvasView.undoRedo.DoUndoRedo;
                  return true;
              }
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
      @Override
      public void onBackPressed() {
          AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
          builder.setTitle("Exit");
          builder.setMessage("Are You Sure?");

          builder.setNegativeButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
              public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                      dialog.dismiss();
                      System.exit(0);
              }
          });   

          builder.setPositiveButton("No", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
              @Override
              public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                  dialog.dismiss();
              }
          });

          AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
          alert.show();

      }
}
```

Activiti_main.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/rect"
    tools:context="com.example.HW3.MainActivity" >

    <com.example.HW3.CanvasView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Consider getting rid of `static` fields and methods and call methods on an object instance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am assuming you have defined your CanvasView in your res/layout/activity_main.xml (and assigned it an id, say "custom_view")
You should not call your Canvas methods statically (directly from the class itself) but from the actual instance created by Android. You can get it by changing your MainActivity to something like this:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
private CanvasView canvasView;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, 
                            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    canvasView = findViewById(R.id.custom_view)
}

...

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

    ...
    canvasView.invalidate();
    ...
}
```

Comment: I edited my question, added my xml file. What should I do in this xml file?

Answer (score 0):

You mention the error states that `invalidate()` isn't a static method. Are you sure you're calling `myCanvasInstance.invalidate()` and **NOT** `CanvasView.invalidate()`?

See these code below to make it clearer:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    // This won't work.
    CanvasView.invalidate();

    // This will.
    CanvasView myView = new CanvasView();
    myView.invalidate();
}
```

In fact, your code seem like treating all method calls as a static call. I don't know whether this is a typo or you are really doing it in your code. The thing is, that's not the right way to do it - `CanvasView` is a class, not an instance/object. You should interact with the instance, not with the class.

For starters, change these line (and all those that are similar to it):

```
CanvasView.getElements().size();
CanvasView.getElements2().add(1);
CanvasView.getLines().remove(CanvasView.getLines().size() - 1);
etc.
```

to something that looks like this:

```
// Define this on the top of your class (outside of any methods).
CanvasView myView;

// Do this on your onCreate() method.
myView = new CanvasView();

// ..and then code like these WILL work; even outside of onCreate().
myView.invalidate();
myView.getElements().size();
myView.getElements2().add(1);
myView.getLines().remove(CanvasView.getLines().size() - 1);
etc.
```

Hope this helped you.

Comment: I get an error: The constructor CanvasView() is undefined

And it says that I should give attributes to CanvasView(), but what should I give it?

Comment: You would need to do **a lot** of things  to deal with custom views in Android -  way more than what I could explain here. I suggest you to use Android's vast amount of built-in views or, if you're determined to make one youself, you can start reading [this](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html).